# in leiningen eclipse Could not locate clojure/contrib/duck_streams__init.class or clojure/contrib/duck_streams.clj

Tags: clojure

I have created one lein project,
than updating its project.clj with dev-dependency of eclips

I ran "lein deps"

it downloaded all dependencies

but into my.m2/repository directory there is no clojure directory.
and this causes me

leiningen.eclipse  Problem loading: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate clojure/contrib/duck_streams__init.class or clojure/contrib/duck_streams.clj on classpath:  (eclipse.clj:1)

error when i ran "lein help" which abandons me to develop with eclipse because i cant run my "lein eclipse" command.

Any solution for this???
Thanks in advance.

my project.clj is given below

```
(

  defproject for_test "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"

  :description "FIXME: write description"

  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.2.1"]]

  :dev-dependencies [[lein-eclipse "1.0.0"]]

)
```

Thnks 'n Regards,
chirag ghiyad

Answer (score 5):

clojure.contrib is a separate library, and so it's dependency needs to be stated explicitly

```
:dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.2.1"]
               [org.clojure/contrib "1.2.0"]]
```

From 1.3 upwards, the monolithic clojure.contrib is no more, and libraries have been split off as [separate libraries](http://dev.clojure.org/display/community/Where+Did+Clojure.Contrib+Go).

These libraries should be found in /m2/org/clojure/clojure and /m2/org/clojure/clojure/contrib. Be aware these aren't put into your classpath automatically, only by running `lein eclipse` after running `lein deps`, which edits your eclipse .classpath and .projects file.

By the way, I would suggest using `lein plugin install lein-ccw "1.2.0"`, which is Clojure 1.3 compatible compared to lein-eclipse. Instead of running `lein eclipse` after `lein deps`, you should use `lein ccw`.

I've always installed either lein-eclipse or lein-ccw plugins into leiningen through a commandline, so I don't know how dev-dependencies should work. In Leiningen 2.0, they separated plugin and dev-dependency functionality.

(Note: both of these plugins are only usable in stable Leiningen 1.7.1)

Comment: i applied your suggestion after deleting my.m2/repository ..but than it gives me below error....----------
1 required artifact is missing.

for artifact: 
  org.apache.maven:super-pom:jar:2.0

from the specified remote repositories:
  central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2),
  clojars (http://clojars.org/repo/)

Comment: are you saying that after running ...lein plugin install lein-eclipse "1.2.0"...i dont need to add this....:dev-dependencies [[lein-eclipse "1.0.0"]]...line in my project.clj??

Comment: My problem is solved after i update my clojure version to 1.7.1,i appreciate your help @NielsK

Answer (score 3):

That answer is out-dated, notice that the package name should be /clojure-contrib rather than /contrib, otherwise

```
lein deps
```

won't find the packages

```
:dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.5.1"]
              [org.clojure/clojure-contrib "1.2.0"]]
```